# mongodb $addToSet _ adding object is not working properly _ mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

according to mongoDB documentation about [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)  operator:

> $addToSet only ensures that there are no duplicate items added to the
> set and does not affect existing duplicate elements. $addToSet does
> not guarantee a particular ordering of elements in the modified set.

so my problem is :

I have an array field that contains  **objects**.

```
foo = [ {a:1, b:2}, {a:3, b:2}]
```

so when I try to push objects in it, the behavior is not working properly :

```
db.myCollection.updateOne({"some_id"}, {$addToSet:{foo:{a:1, b:2}}})
```

the result would be :

```
foo = [ {a:1, b:2}, {a:3, b:2}, {a:1, b:2}]
```

validation on duplicate objects not working. why?

Comment: What Is not working properly?

Comment: @Gibbs validation on duplicate objects not working. why?

Comment: Which version of mongo? It works actually

Comment: @Gibbs v3.6.8  . this is my query :   MyCollection.findOneAndUpdate({
    package_name: req.body.package_name,
}, {
    $addToSet: {
        foo: {a:2, b: 3},

    }

}, { upsert: true, multi: true, new: true })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @Gibbs v3.6.8 . this is my query : MyCollection.findOneAndUpdate({ package_name: req.body.package_name, }, { $addToSet: { foo: {a:2, b: 3}, } }, { upsert: true, multi: true, new: true })

Because mongo considers `2` and `3` as `Double` by default. Hence `2.0` is not same as `2`. So it inserts.

//`NumberInt` solves the issue

To avoid this,

```
db.getCollection('test').findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: ObjectId("5f0d7ab89e001b53e3995a5b")
},
{
  $addToSet: {
    foo: {
      a: NumberInt(2),
      b: NumberInt(3)
    }
  }
},
{
  upsert: true,
  multi: true,
  new: true
})
```